# Google Analytics URL Percent-encoding Issue with Cross Domain Cookie

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

Google Analytics is not understanding a URL Percent-encoding so I can track multiple domains between my "source" domain and my "destination" domain. I'm using Google Tag Manager + the new Universal Analytics.

Is there a macro or rule in google tag manager that I can create to help Google Analytics detect these two URL Percent-encoding as `%2526` for `&` and `%253d` for `=` appropriately? If so, is there any support that could be provided with this issue I'm experiencing?

Here is an example URL (not real):

```
http://subdomain.example.com/adfs/ls/?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2fsub.domain.com%2fwebsite%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3dpassive%26ru%3d%252fwebsite%252fsite%252fexample%252f%253fstuff%253dtypeofuser%2526_ga%253d1.244536837.1471787898.1397850931&wct=2014-04-18T20%3a14%3a54Z
```

As you can see close to the tail end of URL contains my `_ga` cookie that originated from my "source" domain and is getting passed to my "destination" domain. This is a good thing, however GA is not able to read it, because of the URL Percent-encoding shown below:

```
%2526_ga%253d1.244536837.1471787898.1397850931
```

`%2526` is a URL encode for `&`

`%253d` is a URL encode for `=`

Since google analytics is not able to translate the URL Percent-encoding `%2526` and `%253d`  it writes a brand new cookie instead when I look at my cookies when I debug using firebug > cookies tab.

Comment: Evan, why are you encoding '&' and '=' ?

Comment: ADFS URL encodes everything in the URL when its redirected to the authentication server

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found that solves this problem is to append the cookie to the URL again on page load so so the cookie can be read by google analytics.

The regex for .match can be customized with your URLs that you need to filter.

```
var gacookie = window.location.search.match('_ga%253d(.+)&wct=');
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf('_ga') > -1) {
        url += '&_ga=' + gacookie[1]
        parent.location.hash = url
        var hash = location.hash.replace('#', gacookie[1]); 
        if(hash != '') {
        location.hash = '&_ga=' + gacookie[1];
    }
}
```